# Vlcj audio only player

Tags: java, audio-player, vlcj

I am creating a chat application where the user can send audio and video files.

For my video files I have successfully created an embedded video player in my app which will play any video.

But for my audio files I don't want to use an embedded video player with options vout=dummy instead I want to be optimized and use an [DirectAudioPlayer](http://caprica.github.io/vlcj/javadoc/3.3.0/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/player/directaudio/DirectAudioPlayer.html) for my purposes. I took a look at the MediaFactory [create](http://caprica.github.io/vlcj/javadoc/3.3.0/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/player/MediaPlayerFactory.html#newDirectAudioPlayer-java.lang.String-int-int-uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.directaudio.AudioCallback-) but i don't understand how am I suppose to retrieve these parameters for an specific file.

What I want is just one direct audio player in my application which I can reuse for multiple audio files or is this not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [HeadlessMediaPlayer](https://caprica.github.io/vlcj/javadoc/3.3.0/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/player/MediaPlayerFactory.html#newHeadlessMediaPlayer).

This is basically the same as the EmbeddedMediaPlayer that you're already using, but with no API to do with displaying the video.

A word of caution though if you play a video through the HeadlessMediaPlayer, rather than just an audio file, LibVLC will open a native window and play the video - you can suppress this by passing "--no-video" via the MediaPlayerFactory.

The DirectAudioPlayer is used when you want to access the audio buffer in your application - i.e. "direct" access to the native audio buffer. You would then have to use JavaSound or something to actually play the audio. So I don't think this is what you want.

Comment: Ahh I see , So direct audio player it's for low level audio access only. Thanks I will look into it